# How can I figure out if the NSNumber I get back from -valueForKey: was initially an int or float?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

The reason is I must get back the exact value as it was in the property. So if it was a float, I want to call -floatValue. But if it was an int, I want to call -intValue.

Is NSNumber remembering how it was initialized?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NSNumber is toll-free bridged with CFNumber (see, amongst other sources, the text at the top of the [CFNumber reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html)). So you can use [CFNumberGetType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNumberGetType). E.g.

```
- (void)logTypeOf:(NSNumber *)number
{
    switch(CFNumberGetType((CFNumberRef)number))
    {
        case kCFNumberSInt8Type:    NSLog(@"8bit signed integer"); break;
        case kCFNumberSInt16Type:   NSLog(@"16bit signed integer"); break;
        case kCFNumberSInt32Type:   NSLog(@"32bit signed integer"); break;

        /* ... etc, for all of:
           kCFNumberSInt64Type
           kCFNumberFloat32Type
           kCFNumberFloat64Type
           kCFNumberCharType
           kCFNumberShortType
           kCFNumberIntType
           kCFNumberLongType
           kCFNumberLongLongType
           kCFNumberFloatType
           kCFNumberDoubleType
           kCFNumberCFIndexType
           kCFNumberNSIntegerType
           kCFNumberCGFloatType
        */
   }
}
```

EDIT: looking more thoroughly at the documentation, [CFNumberIsFloatType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNumberIsFloatType) would appear to do exactly what you want without the complexity. So:

```
if(CFNumberIsFloatType((CFNumberRef)number))
{
    NSLog(@"this was a float");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"this was an int");
}
```

Comment: +1 Very cool (and much better than the cast-and-compare hack that came to mind when I read the title).

Comment: This is a good answer, however it's worth noting the `NSNumber` method [`objCType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-DontLinkElementID_7) which likely uses `CFNumberGetType()`. Also be aware that both the method and the function have notes to the effect that the type they return may not precisely match the initialization type.